# Prompt engineering issue with chatGPT

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am trying to do some prompt engineering with gpt 3.5 model based on guidance https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/prompt-engineering/six-strategies-for-getting-better-results

here is my data:

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()

response = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "Tell if the text delimited by triple quotes is a valid question to ask a Tarot reader.  Respond in yes or no only. \"\"\" Should I relocate to another city for my job ?\"\"\""
    },
    {
      "role": "assistant",
      "content": "Do not ignore this text while answering. Tarot cards are not typically used for predicting academic performance or specific future outcomes. Tarot cards are not meant to predict specific future events. Tarot can help in making decisions such as relocating to a new city for job."
    }
  ],
  temperature=1,
  max_tokens=256,
  top_p=1,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0
)
```

I am expecting a response "yes" based on what i am guiding in the assistant text. however, i get a "no" and this puzzles me